# Fastest way to move files on a Windows System

Tags: windows, performance, batch-file, copy-paste

I want to **move about 800gb of data from an NTFS storage device to a FAT32 device** (both are external hard drives), on a Windows System.

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. Simply using cut-paste?
2. Using the command prompt ? (`move`)
3. Writing a batch file to copy a small chunks of data on a given interval ?
4. Use some specific application that does the job for me?
5. Or any better idea...?

What is the most safe, efficient and fast way to achieve such a time consuming process?

Comment: Make sure all the files on your NTFS drive are valid for FAT32, i.e. nothing over 2G.  I did the same thing with robocopy a few weeks ago.

Comment: I'm about to move 1.5TB from a Backblaze backup drive to my new replacement 7200rpm drive on Windows 10 and am shocked that more people haven't been asking this question since 2008 (or providing new answers). Hopefully Robocopy (the leading answer right now) is still the best idea because that's probably what I'll try.

Comment: This is a top hit in google for "windows cmd fastest way to move files" so I wanted to add a trick: Sometimes moving the location to your files is faster than moving the files to the location.  That is, I'm moving 500k files to another folder, leaving 20k files behind.  It's faster to move the 20k files to a staging location, rename/move the parent folder of the 500k, and then rename the 20k files' parent to the original name.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)

You can restart the command and it'll resume.  I use it all the time over the network.  Works on large files as well.

Comment: Robocopy also includes a commandline switch to delay between packets, making it co-exist nicely with other traffic. My experience with Robocopy is that you end up around 2x the throughput of the Windows XP  Explorer.

Comment: Perfect...just what i needed!  I am currently using robocopy for copying the data.  Everyone, thanks for the input.

Comment: /mt option makes it a multi-threaded copy with 8 threads - i hear this option has been added on robocopy supplied with Windows Server 2008 R2 and higher - since I don't have it, I try to copy e.g. 4 directories at a time, issuing 4 robocopy commands

Comment: Robocopy was also recommend here (with tips): http://superuser.com/a/364995/74576

Comment: The OP mentions *moving* rather than *copying* files. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) point out that the  `/mov` option "deletes them from the source after they're copied."

Answer (score 6):

I would physically move the hard dsk if possible.

Comment: turn off the storage devices, unplug cables, remove hard drive, insert drive into new storage device, attach cables, turn back on...

Comment: DO NOT PUT the drive into your raid subsystem- they'll typically initialize (wipe) a disk as soon as you do. Ask me how I know.

Answer (score 4):

I've found fast copy to be quite good for this sort of thing. Its a gui tool ....

http://www.ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en

Answer (score 2):

If you have to move it over a network, you want to use FTP between the servers.  The Windows File system will get bogged down with chatty protocols.

Comment: You'd have to zip it up first. FTP is slow with thousands of files.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) to be pretty fast and handy. Allegedly Fastcopy (as [suggested by benlumley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364367/fastest-way-to-move-files-on-a-windows-system#364378)) is even faster, but I don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using WinRar or a zipping tool. Big "files" are moved quicker than lots of small ones.
Most zipping tools allow to split the archive(zip) files into multiple archives.

You might even reduce the size a bit when you turn on compression.

Answer (score 1):

Command Line: xcopy is probably your best bet

Command Reference:
http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

Answer (score 1):

I used Teracopy and copied 50+GB to a 128GB flash drive.
Too almost 48 hours...had to do it twice because had a power
hiccup.  Had to re-format and start over...Not my favorite thing
to do...

Comment: that seems unusually slow, only 290kb/sec... You can get USB3 128Gb flash drives that do almost 9Mb/sec random 4k write now, and peak write of almost 250Mb/sec.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest way to copy files is use **robocopy** as pointed by Pyrolistical in above post. its very flexible and powerful. 
If command doesn't work from your dos prompt directly then try with powershell option like below example.

**Must Check the documentation for this command before using it "robocopy /?".**

```
powershell "robocopy  'Source' 'destination' /E /R:3 /W:10 /FP /MT:25 /V" 

/E - Copy subdirectory including empty ones.
/R - Retry 3 times if failed.
/W - wait for 10 seconds between retries.
/FP - include full path name in output.
/MT - Multi thread.
/V - verbose output.
```

Comment: Hi from 2022.  These flags are still good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment a comment about multithreading, from @hello_earth, 201510131124, but I don't have enough reputation points on Stackoverflow (I've mostly posted on Superuser up until now) :
 
Multithreading is typically **not** efficient when it comes to copying files from 1 storage device to 1 other, because the fastest throughput is reached for sequential reads, and using multiple threads will make a HDD rattle and grind like crazy to read or write several files at the same time, and since a HDD can only access one file at a time it must read or write one chunk from a file then move to a chunk from another file located in a different area, which slows down the process considerably (I don't know how a SSD would behave in such a case). It is both inefficient and potentially harmful : the mechanical stress is considerably higher when the heads are moving repeatedly across the platters to reach several areas in short succession, rather than staying at the same spot to parse a large contiguous file.

I discovered this when batch checking the MD5 checksums of a very large folder full of video files with md5deep : with the default options the analysis was multithreaded, so there were 8 threads with an i7 6700K CPU, and it was excruciatingly slow. Then I added the -j1 option, meaning 1 thread, and it proceeded **much** faster, since the files were now read sequentially.

Another consideration that derives from this is that the transfer speed will be significantly higher if files are not fragmented, and also, more marginally, if they are located at the begining of a hard disk drive, corresponding to the outermost parts of the platters, where the linear velocity is maximum (that aspect is irrelevant with a solid state drive or other flash memory based device).

Also, the original poster wanted “the most safe, efficient and fast way to achieve such a time consuming process” – I'd say that one has to choose a compromise favoring **either** speed/efficiency, **or** safety : if you want safety, you have to check that each file was copied flawlessly (by checking MD5 checksums, or with something like WinMerge) ; if you don't do that, you can never be 100% sure that there weren't some SNAFUs in the process (hardware or software issues) ; if you do that, you have to spend twice as much time on the task.

For instance : I relied on a little tool called SynchronizeIt! for my file copying purposes, because it has the huge advantage compared to most similar tools of preserving all timestamps (including directory timestamps, like Robocopy does with the /DCOPY:T switch), and it has a streamlined interface with just the options I need. But I discovered that some files were always corrupted after a copy, truncated after exactly 25000 bytes (so the copy of a 1GB video for instance had 25000 good bytes then 1GB of 00s, the copy process was abnormally fast, took only a split second, which triggered my suspicion in the first place). I reported this issue to the author a first time in 2010, but then he chalked it up to a hardware malfunction, and didn't think twice about it. I still used SI, but started to check files thoroughly **every time** I made a copy (with WinMerge or Total Commander) ; when files ended up corrupted I used Robocopy instead (files which were corrupted with SynchronizeIt, when they were copied with Robocopy, then copied again with SynchronizeIt, were copied flawlessly, so there was something in the way they were recorded on the NTFS partition which confused that software, and which Robocopy somehow fixed). Then in 2015 I reported it again, after having identified more patterns regarding which files were corrupted : they had all been downloaded with particular download managers. That time the author did some digging, and found the explanation : it turned out that his tool had trouble copying files with the little known “sparse” attribute, and that some download managers set this attribute to save space when downloading files in multiple chunks. He provided me with an updated version which correctly copies sparse files, but hasn't released it on his website (the currently available version is 3.5 from 2009, the version I now use is a 3.6 beta from October 2015), so if you want to try that otherwise excellent software, be aware of that bug, and whenever you copy important files, thoroughly verify if each copied file is identical to the source (using a different tool), before deleting them from the source.