# DOS Batch file to move 2000 files every 10 minutes

Tags: dos

Is it possible to create a DOS script that will move 2000 files to another folder every 10 minutes?

For example:

C:\MyFolder\

Every 10 minutes move 2000 files to C:\MyNewFolder\

Thank you!

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364367/fastest-way-to-move-files-on-a-windows-system

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like xcopy as recommended, however I would use the date flag to specify only copying new files.  Just omit the date and it will copy only newer files.

```
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.

  /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
               If no date is given, copies only those files whose
               source time is newer than the destination time.

  /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
```

`xcopy C:\Source Z:\Destination /C /D /E`

Comment: Read the question again. He doesnt want to copy files; rather he wants to do some operation every 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Use Schtasks.

You may want to look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx